# Pass a label in a loop (TiKz)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to reproduce the attached figure but I encounter some troubles for the display of labels.

[image]

```
   \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
   \usepackage{color}
   \tikzset{
    zellige/.pic={
    \draw[ultra thick] (0,0)--(3,3)--(4,2)--(6,2)--(4,0)
        --(5,-2)--(4,-2)--(3,-1)--(2,-2)--(1,-2)--cycle; 
    }
     }
   \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[cyan] (0,-14) grid (42,3);
   \foreach \i in {0,...,9}
   \foreach \j in {0,...,3}{
     \pic at (4*\i,-4*\j){zellige};}
       \foreach \i in {0,...,9}
   \foreach \j in {10,...,19}{
     \node[draw,circle,inner sep=15pt,] at (4*\i +2.5,0.1){\LARGE \j};
    }
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```

Comment: One common trick in Ti*k*Z is to use the `.try` handler. Ideally speaking, you add `\pgfkeys{ /Fabrice/\i/\j/.try }` in the for loop. And then, before the for loop, add `\pgfkeys{ /Fabrice/\i/\j/.code = draw the arrow }`.

Comment: Or, you can use `coordinate` in a `pic` and name every instance of `pic`s. That will give you access to those corner points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would just add the node to the definition of the `pic` (since `pic`s can take arguments).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
    zellige/.pic={
    \draw[ultra thick] (0,0)--(3,3)--(4,2)--(6,2)--(4,0)
        --(5,-2)--(4,-2)--(3,-1)--(2,-2)--(1,-2)--cycle; 
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=15pt,font=\LARGE] at (2.75,0.25) {#1};  
    }
     }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[cyan] (0,-14) grid (42,3);
   \foreach \i in {0,...,9}
   {\foreach \j [evaluate=\j as \k using {int(10+10*\j+\i)}] in {0,...,3}{
     \pic at (4*\i,-4*\j){zellige=\k};}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for your comment, I added some vectors. (I do not know what your command `\vv` does.) If you want to use `every node/.style` and give some nodes extra font information, you could use `font` and `node font`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\tikzset{
    zellige/.pic={
    \draw[ultra thick] (0,0)--(3,3)--(4,2)--(6,2)--(4,0)
        --(5,-2)--(4,-2)--(3,-1)--(2,-2)--(1,-2)--cycle; 
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=15pt,font=\LARGE] at (2.75,0.25) {#1};  
    }
     }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, every node/.style={transform
shape,node font=\LARGE}]
   \draw[cyan] (0,-14) grid (42,3);
   \foreach \i in {0,...,9}
   {\foreach \j [evaluate=\j as \k using {int(10+10*\j+\i)}] in {0,...,3}{
     \pic at (4*\i,-4*\j){zellige=\k};}}
   \draw[color=red,-latex,very thick] (0,0) 
   node [left,node font=\boldmath\Huge]{{$\vec u$}} -- ++ (12,-8);   
   \draw[color=red,-latex,very thick] (20,2) 
   node [left,font=\boldmath\Huge]{{$\vec w$}} -- ++ (12,-8);     
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, these vectors are boldface, and `\Huge` does have an impact. And by using `transform shape` you do not have to add `scale=0.5` twice.

Comment: I would like the size of the name of the vectors to be bigger. If I do this `\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=0.5, every node/.style={scale=0.8,font=\boldmath\LARGE}]` it does not work. Thank you

Comment: @Fabrice It does work if you switch into math mode: `\tikzset{
    zellige/.pic={
    \draw[ultra thick] (0,0)--(3,3)--(4,2)--(6,2)--(4,0)
        --(5,-2)--(4,-2)--(3,-1)--(2,-2)--(1,-2)--cycle; 
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=15pt,font=\LARGE\boldmath] at (2.75,0.25) {$#1$};  
    }
     }`

Comment: I'm sorry but this code does not work. I'm talking about the labels u, v, w ... vectors with `\draw[color=red,->] (0,14) node [left]{{$\vv u$}} --(12,6);`

Comment: @Fabrice I added some vectors and find that it does work. The only way I see that it may not work is that `\vv`, whose definition I do not know, does something unexpected.

Comment: I think I'm not clear enough !
I have to reduce the size of the image but if I do this `\begin{tikzpicture}
      [scale=0.5, every node/.style={scale=0.5,font=\boldmath\LARGE}]\end{tikzpicture}`, the vector labels are too small

Comment: @Fabrice I added something. And I would like to encourage you to write a new question if that does not help. Asking questions is free, and these things may be interesting for others and are not directly related to the original question.

Comment: This is not necessary because you have responded perfectly to what I seek to do. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

It is enough to place the labels in the loop that builds the zelliges.

[image: labels]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
   \usepackage{color}
   \tikzset{
    zellige/.pic={
    \draw[ultra thick] (0,0)--(3,3)--(4,2)--(6,2)--(4,0)
        --(5,-2)--(4,-2)--(3,-1)--(2,-2)--(1,-2)--cycle; 
    }
     }
   \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[cyan] (0,-14) grid (42,3);
   \foreach \i in {0,...,9}{
         \foreach \j [evaluate=\j as \lab using int((\j+1)*10+\i)]in {0,...,3}{
                \pic at (4*\i,-4*\j){zellige};
                \node[draw,circle,inner sep=15pt] at (4*\i+2.5,-4*\j){\LARGE \lab};}
     }
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```